# How to use custom fonts via pub folder?

Tags: magento2, fonts

I would like to call paid fonts via pub folder. I create the specific font folder in pub i.e

> pub/static/frontend/Mageplaza/ultimate/en_US/fonts

and linked it my custom.css file font family is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in a wrong way, As per magento standards, do not upload any files directly to the pub/ folder.

if you want to add font family upload the File under

> web/css/fonts

in your custom theme or Module View folder.
To call the font face,  create/modify custom.css in following path,

> web/css/custom.css

Comment: I placed it in my default theme but it's not working, that's why I'm trying different way to use the fonts.

Comment: old post but this approach by Magento really irks me. Every time you deploy static files, visitors are made to download a new copy of the exact same font. It's wasteful!
Font files don't change the way css do. They should be OUTSIDE the versioned tree.